# jQuery remove element from the stack

Tags: jquery

How to remove element from the stack, but not from the DOM?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [.not() method](http://api.jquery.com/not/). It accepts a list of elements as well as a selector.

Comment: Yea found it. Forgot about it damn... :) There is selector as well btw. I was thinking about filter method as well, for more flexible solution as well.